# Get all GIF images saved on iPhone/iPad camera roll

Tags: ios, camera, gif

As far as I know, it is very easy to get all the videos from the Camera Roll, just by doing something like this:

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, nil];

    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**My question is, how is it possible to get all the GIF saved on the camera roll?**

I have downloaded the app 'GifBoom Pro' and it does it.

Thank you very much.

Comment: This can't be done with the `UIImagePickerController`. Look at `ALAssetsLibrary` for accessing images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old question. But for anyone else to come, you'll need to use the `Photos` framework and use `requestImageDataForAsset:imageData:imageUTI,Orientation,Info` and compare the image UTI against the string of `com.compuserve.gif`. ALAssetsLibrary will become deprecated by iOS 9.0